# Build/Install Instructions for MyMonero App on Android using node/npm

Tags: development, mymonero, build, android-wallet

I would like to test the [MyMonero App](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js) on Android in its current state of development.

Please provide instructions for how to use node/npm to build the app and install in on Android. Assume I have a new Android phone I am willing to use solely for this purpose. Therefore I am not concerned about data loss or usability of my phone for anything other than [MyMonero](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are instructions in the Github repo:

https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js/blob/master/docs/PRODUCTION_BUILDS.md